# JavaScript Keyup Not Firing Sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, dom-events

Sometimes the event can be fired but sometimes nothing happen.
I have no idea why.
Below is my code for .aspx and javascript.
It does hit alert('register') everytime the page loads.
.aspx

```
  <span class="searchInputContainer" data-moreresults="<%= SeeMoreText %>" data-noresult="<%= NoResultText %>">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchNew" runat="server" CssClass="SearchTextBox" UseSubmitBehaviour="false" AutoPostBack="false" MaxLength="255" EnableViewState="False" aria-label="Search"></asp:TextBox>
            <a class="dnnSearchBoxClearText" title="<%= ClearQueryText %>"></a>
        </span>
```

JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    function fn() {
        alert('fn');
        document.getElementById("<%= txtSearchNew.ClientID %>")
            .addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    alert('enter');
                    redirectNew();
                }
            });
    };
   
    function redirectNew() {
    alert('redirect');
    
        var input = document.getElementById("<%= txtSearchNew.ClientID %>").value
        var inputSplit = input.split(" ");
        var param = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < inputSplit.length; i++) {
            if (i < (inputSplit.length - 1)) {

                param += inputSplit[i] + "+";
            }
            else {
                param += inputSplit[i];
            }

        }
    alert('https://abc.local/index.php?search=' + param);
        window.open('https://abc.local/index.php?search=' + param, 'searchTab');

    }
```

Anyone has idea about it?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658719/using-clientid-to-get-value-from-textbox-does-not-work-with-javascript

Comment: I tried your code and is working correctly if element ids are set by default (not dynamically from server). Have you tried calling 'redirectNew()' from your browser console after page renders?

Comment: Yes, it works in console, but I dont know why it wont fire when using it normally. I also put the javascript after the DOM

Comment: Try these three: 1=> make id to be static in your control and test it (ClientIDMode="Static"). 2=> try to register your script from code behind  (Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript). 3=> add your code to a JS file and add "defer" to your script tag (it tells your browser to parse the page first and then load/run your scripts).